# fortran 77 default arguments

Tags: default-value, fortran77

I’m at the point where I have to add an argument to a subroutine that is called in several areas of the code. The new argument is only useful in the new code I’m writing. Adding the argument everywhere it’s called is tedious and invasive, so I’m looking for an alternative.

In C++ I would make the default value of the argument `NULL`, and I would only use the values if the pointer is not `NULL` in the routine.

To mimic this in Fortran I renamed the old subroutine and made a new subroutine with the old name that calls the new subroutine with the old code inside of it. The extra argument is given a dummy memory space before calling the new subroutine with the old code. I know that’s confusing. Here's an example:

```
subroutine func(a,b,c,d)
! Declare a,b,c,d

! compute values

return
end
```

I want to add the argument `e` here. So I do this:

```
subroutine func_with_e(a,b,c,d,e)
! Declare a,b,c,d,e

! compute values

return
end

subroutine func(a,b,c,d)
! Declare a,b,c,d
double precision e(length)

! fill e with dummy values

call func_with_e(a,b,c,d,e)

return
end
```

The way I wrote this `e` is always used (unlike the C++ `NULL` pointer example), but I could always add a second argument to flag whether to use `e` or not. The existing code base calls the function `func`, and when I want to use `e` I use `func_with_e`.

Is this a viable strategy? Can anyone speak from experience if this enhances or degrades maintainability? It’s quite inconvenient to not have default values, but it is obviously inconvenient to go through this nonsense too. Is there any way I can get this behavior to happen at compile time rather than runtime? Note that I can't use any Fortran 90 or higher functionality.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses everyone. I have decided against ENTRY because it is just too unclear.

My only concern is the long-term viability of this approach. What if one of these functions gets 10-20 different "signatures". Every single one would have to be updated, and the chance for error increases. I guess that is life though.

Comment: Writing new code in FORTRAN 77 is certainly not going to enhance maintainability, so why not go straight for using `ENTRY`?

Comment: Thanks for the edit first of all. Second, these guys insist this is as maintainable as a code can be. I can't change the language. I need to find a way to do the best with what I have.

Comment: My point, although perhaps not well made, was that, to a F77 programmer `ENTRY` may be quite natural here.

Comment: Haha, I thought you were using `ENTRY` to refer to any other language. Like why not go straight for java/C++, etc. Thanks, I will look up `ENTRY`.

Comment: You could task the genius who insists on using f77 with going through the code and adding the extra argument everywhere.

Comment: :) That won't help me with my problem, but it will help me get through the rest of the day without blowing my brains out. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, I believe your approach is the best one given the constraint.  `ENTRY` is i think depreciated/obsolescent in newer versions (for good reason IMO), so best avoided if possible.

Comment: @george `ENTRY` is obsolescent in F2008, yes. I did mean to write something more, but didn't. In summary, I agree that the approach presented is acceptable, but the "best" one is one that fits the current codebase. If `ENTRY` was used by the F77-minded developers then that may win.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need FORTRAN77, you can use ENTRY statement as suggested in commentaries. But this feature was made [deprecated](http://www.codezone.co.uk/fortran/deprecatedfeatures.shtml#ENTRY) in any newer Fortran version. Also it makes your code less readable (like GOTO statements).

Thus, your approach of introducing a new function with a new name seems as good as ENTRY to me.

If you want to change argument list of the existing subroutine, you can use [gen-interfaces](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-69E564AA-488B-4D4B-9B54-B580C454CA68.htm) (& warn-interfaces) compiler switches or some good static analyser to find all places where it is used.